# CakePHP v1.3: Full Code Coverage Report

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, simpletest

In CakePHP v2.x, you can generate a unit testing code coverage report [from the command line](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#running-tests-from-command-line) using [a test suite](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#creating-test-suites) that fires all of your app's tests and the `--coverage-html` option. (Example: `cake test app All --coverage-html=tmp/coverage/`)

I've been searching for an equivalent for Cake v1.3, which uses [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/). When [testing via the browser](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Testing.html#running-core-test-cases), it's possible to view code coverage for each individual test case, but not for the whole **App** category.

Similarly, [running tests from the command line](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Testing.html#running-tests-in-the-command-line) via `cake testsuite app all` does not seem capable of taking any command-line options for generating coverage output. The v1.3 Book doesn't dive into any more detail on the subject.

**So my question is: Is there a way to generate a "full" code coverage report for a Cake *v1.3* application from the command line?**

---

***Additional Information for future searchers:***

Per @mark-story's suggestion, I tried running `cake testsuite app all cov`, but that  produces the following fatal error for me:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CodeCoverageManager' not found in
    cake/tests/lib/reporter/cake_base_reporter.php on line 131
```

This is with SimpleTest v1.0.1 [in my `app/vendors/simpletest/` folder](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Testing.html#installing-simpletest). I tried upgrading to SimpleTest [v1.1.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simpletest/files/simpletest/simpletest_1.1/), but that resulted in a different fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CakeCliReporter::SimpleReporter() in
    cake/tests/lib/reporter/cake_base_reporter.php on line 85
```

Comment: I am probably the only person left on the planet that is concerned about unit testing an old 1.3 Cake app...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try addin 'cov' to the end of the cli runner arguments. The help() command indicates this will work. It has been a whilre, but I think this will output the % of code covered. There is no way to generate a detailed set of coverage reports like you can with phpunit.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think you're right that that's as good as I'm going to get without spending days trying to build something myself. _(I'm going to leave your answer unaccepted for a while on the [extreme] outside chance that someone else has discovered a method to accomplish this.)_